# How to retain environment variables across sessions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

I have already referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249980/unable-to-reference-environment-variables) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460633/linux-unix-environment-variables).

I would like to set few variables as global/system level environment variables which I would like to initialize once and be available anytime I login. I don't wish to reassign them again and again.

Below are what I did.

**Step - 1 (in command line terminal)**

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/spark"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/spark/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH"
```

**Step - 2 (in .bashrc file)**

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/spark"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/spark/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH"
```

**step -2a refresh/reload bashrc file**

```
source .bashrc
```

The above two steps didn't work. Meaning once I logout and login, when I issue `printenv` command, I don't see them

So, I thought of navigating to the below folder based on SO posts

```
cd /etc/environment -what should I do in this file?

cd /etc/profile - what should I do in this file?

cd /etc/profile.d/ - I see 4 files here as shown below (don't know what to do from here)

apps-bin-path.sh  bash_completion.sh  cedilla-portuguese.sh  gtk-accessibility.sh  vte-2.91.sh
```

My profile file looks like as below

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

How can I set these environment variables for eternity? However many terminals I open, I would like to have them and use them.

Comment: Of course they are lost, when you log out. But when the shell is interactive, ~/.bashrc should be source. I suggest that you put a `set -x` temporarily as the first statement in your .bashrc, and open a new shell. You will get plenty of output, but you will see, what statements are executed. Please also post your bash version (`echo $BASH_VERSION`).

Comment: hi @user1934428 - Can't I set this variables forever? Meaning I will be using them everyday. How can I set this up in my profile? So, everytime I login, it is available irrespective of how many terminals I open?

Comment: @user1934428 - updated the post with `bash` and `profile` file details. One thing is, I am able to see `PYENV_ROOT` and `PATH` defined before the `If` clause

Comment: An environment variable, by definition, belongs to a **process**. When the process is gone, the environment dies with it. It is just inherited by the child processes. But you can of course provice a new, suitable environment for a new process. One purpose, why bash automatically processes certain files on startup, is to allow you to set up your environment.

Comment: Yes, thanks I understand now. so I would like to set up my environment for SPARK. Hence I require those variables listed to be available upon startup. I use the server only for SPARK. thats the purpose of our server..

Comment: I have never worked with `pyenv`, but the way you use it, looks odd to me: AFIK, one thing `pyenv` is doing, is to modify your PATH. But you are running `pyenv` in a child process, which means that you don't see these changes. Well, if `pyenv` just outputs the commands for environment manipulation to stdout, this would work. In case you don't see the expected effect from `pyenv`, I suggest you post a new question for this topic, and appropriate tags.

Comment: Actually my question is not about `pyenv`. Its only about `setting environment variables` which is available everytime I login (in any number of terminals)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221490/discussion-between-user1934428-and-the-great).

Answer (score 0):

Read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile).

> /etc/environment - what should I do in this file?

This is a system-wide configuration file, so it's used by **all** users on the system. You need 'root' permissions to edit it.

> /etc/profile - what should I do in this file?

This is your personal shell initialization script.

Also, you're not the only one who asked this question before in regards to Sparky.
See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299147/setting-variables-in-etc-environment-not-having-an-affect-but-setting-them-in-c).